# Partial specialization for class method

Tags: c++

I'm trying to specialize a method of a (non-templated!) class. Apparently, it's not possible, however I am struggling to figure out why, or how to overcome the problem.

```
class MyClass {

public:
        template <typename... T>
        auto MyMethod(T... t) -> void { std::cout << "Original" << std::endl; }

        template <typename... T>
        auto MyMethod<int, T...>(int value, T... t) -> void { std::cout << "Specialization" << value << std::endl; }

};

int main(void) {
        MyClass myClass;
        myClass.MyMethod<char, char>('c', 'c');
        myClass.MyMethod<int, char>(123, 'c');

        return 0;
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
test.cpp:10:49: error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘MyMethod<int, T ...>’ is not allowed
   10 |  auto MyMethod<int, T...>(int value, T... t) -> void { std::cout << "Specialization" << value << std::endl; }
```

It seems that there would be no reason for this to be impossible (with a template class it makes sense that the entire class has to be specialized too). What am I missing? Is it literally not possible?

Comment: I think you are just trying to overload, not specialize. Try without the `<>` after the function name.

Comment: @Ben Evidently an overload works here. I still wonder why would a specialization not work? The weird thing is that if these were functions and not methods, it would. Those methods aren't even virtual, why would there be a difference?

Comment: *"if these were functions and not methods, it would"* - No it won't. Either free or members, function templates cannot be partially specialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only classes can be *partially* specialized; methods can only be *fully* specialized. As your methods still have template arguments (`T`) that are not specified, this means a partial method specialization.

If you would use these template arguments for a class (and call a non-templated member function of that class) then this should be possible.